# How to calculate water temperature from a room temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

e.g. My room temperature is about 33 degree celsius

How can I calculate water temperature in the tank in my bathroom?

Note that my tank is one side open up and it build up from bricks

Comment: There is only one way to get accurate results: Measure it. Although after sufficient waiting time the temperature will equilibrate with the room temperature (more or less, evaporation cooling might have to be considered and can be relevant in some scenarios).

Answer (score 1):

When you fill the tank with water of some temperature, it will gradually stabilize on the same temperature as is you room temperature, given sufficiently long time. If you want to know answer before the stabilization, you need to know a lot of other variables like initial temperature of the water, time elapsed after the filling etc.